# Recommendations for UML tool to model C++/QNX (Eclipse-CDT)?

Tags: uml, eclipse-cdt, qnx

Can someone recommend a UML modelling toolfor QNX? I'm not bothered about generating code (although it'd be nice) I just want to knock something up and I'm looking for some steer.

I've had a quick look at the mdt-uml2tools Eclipse plugin but I don't seem to be able to do compositions/aggregations, I guess because it's java related.

Any thoughts or recommendations?

Comment: Do you mean a UML tool hosted on QNX or simply a UML tool for *designing* QNX systems (perhaps integrated with Momentics - which is Eclipse based)?  If the former, I doubt such a thing exists since QNX is intended as an embedded systems platform not a general application platform. If the latter, than there are a number of tools, but you may have to eschew Momentics/Eclipse integration.  A recommendation would depend on your development host platform.

Comment: I mean the latter. Since I'm developing C++ in Eclipse I was looking for a plug-in recommendation really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of comercial UML tool ventors support Eclipse integartion, for example:

[Visual Paradigm SDE](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/)

[Enterprise Architect Eclipse MDG Link](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/mdg/link/eclipse/index.html)

[Enterprise Architect Eclipse MDG Integration](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/mdg/int/eclipse/index.html)

However if code generation is not a requirement, do you require such tight integration with Eclipse?

Comment: no, I probably don't 'need' the tight integration, I just liked the idea of having the code and UML together in the same IDE.

Comment: @qyeBurro: If cost is an issue, and integration not, then Umbrello is a well featured open source tool, but only on Linux and OSX. http://uml.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

I've been very happy with the standalone, free [BoUML](http://www.bouml.fr/).  I've used it both on small and large projects.  It will generate code, but I prefer it more for reverse engineering/analysis and sketching ideas.